# How to see when windows XP was on and off

Tags: windows, windows-xp, startup

Is there way to see when windows XP was on and off?

I have important system on windows XP computer, so I want to see when it was on and off.

If this is not possible, it would be also usefull for me to see what it was up(started), if off is not available.

Comment: "See" from a remote machine like a network monitoring solution or "see" like Windows Event Log?

Comment: I have physical access to that windows XP computer, and only physical access, no remote access is enable. So I am talking about "Windows Event Log", but I do not know how to use it or where to find this information. Also if there is some external program that can pars and show this info it would be useful for me.

Answer (score 1):

There is an alternative to using the event log and such, unless you need to go back in time from this point. How about pinging it on a regular basis (scripted) or using some sort of network monitoring software (like nagios)?

That's how we tell when servers are up and down.

Comment: good idea, but not sure can I access it from my office computer I will investigate that. Event Log is fine for me, but I need to figure out how to use it :-)